# Microsoft Ads inside UWP Webview

Tags: c#, uwp, ads, windows-dev-center

I've built an C# UWP app showing some HTML content I get from WordPress inside a WebView.

Now I'd like to show some ads inside that WebView below the HTML content. I don't want to use the C# Ads SDK.

[According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-html-5-and-javascript), I need to manually add the WinJS library (which I've done) and also install and reference the Microsoft Advertising SDK. However, since the project is a C# UWP app I can't reference the `Microsoft Advertising SDK for JavaScript`.

```
<!-- Advertising required references -->
<script src="//Microsoft.Advertising.JavaScript/ad.js"></script>
```

How can I reference the necessary ad.js file? Can I somehow download or extract this from the SDK? Or is there another, official way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'd like to show some ads inside that WebView below the HTML content.

In WinJS UWP application, you could use html as ad container to display AD, but in C# UWP it's not allowed. Because, you could not get [`Microsoft.Advertising.JavaScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-html-5-and-javascript) sdk with `<script src="//Microsoft.Advertising.JavaScript/ad.js"></script>`, and it is not available in C# UWP project even if you copy the `ad.js` to `C#` UWP project manually.

The best practice that implement AD in `C#` UWP project is to use `Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML` for the detail steps please refer [AdControl in XAML and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net).